# Can my cyborg idea work?

Tags: science-based, biology, science-fiction, xenobiology

I'm writing a book where the main character is a cyborg, it's going to be a hard-science book and my idea is like a brain in a jar with the intact brain within a structure that pumps artificial blood to the brain, how could this device pump blood to the brain if (the brain) has no carotid arteries? Perhaps intravenously? But those needles would need to be changed regularly right? (I'm new to this site I hope I'm doing this right >.<)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't fully understand what this question is about. Is it about how pumps work? When you say you have an "intact brain" one would assume it is complete with its supporting structures, i.e., arteries, veins, cerebro-spinal fluid and so on. (And the carotid arteries do not reach the brain anyway; they feed oxygenated blood into the [Circle of Willis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_Willis), from where the brain is supplied with blood through the anterior / posterior cerebral / communicating arteries, together with the middle cerebral arteries which branch off the internal carotids.)

Comment: The `science-based` and `hard-science` tags should not be used together, nor either one with `science-fiction`.  Given this question, I'd suggest removing `hard-science` (read its tag wiki entry to understand why) and `science-based`.  BTW, Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  Please be sure to take the [tour] and read through the [FAQ] to better understand how this site works.

Comment: The question is poorly formed. There's more to the brain than carotid arteries. Are we talking about the Circle of Willis being removed? The vertebral arteries? Middle cerebral? Lacunar arterioles? Etc. etc. What about the cerebral sinuses? The brain has a vascular architecture unlike any other part of the body. Arteries aren't matched to veins. Has the brain's entire vascular system been removed or just the carotids?

Comment: Why would your brain in a jar not have it's normal circulatory system intact in the he first place? What purpose could it possibly serve going to the not inconsiderable trouble of removing those structures? especially when simply leaving them in situ would make the delivery of any necessery blood or blood substitute so (relatively) simple.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are asking for a replacement to the carotid artery: Artificial blood vessels are one possibility. Expanded polytetrafluoroethylene can be used to create blood vessels of both short and long diameters. This material is inert and does not degrade.

Information from [Artificial small-diameter blood vessels: materials, fabrication, surface modification, mechanical properties, and bioactive functionalities](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2020/tb/c9tb01849b)